# Использование конструкторов базового класса в наследнике

Tags: c++, конструктор, конструктор-копирования

Пытаюсь использовать копирующий конструктор базового класса в производном:

```
#include <vector>

struct Base {
    Base() noexcept {}
    Base(const Base&) noexcept {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
    using Base::Base;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Derived> vec = {Base{}, Base{}};
}
```

Однако получаю ошибку:

```
error: could not convert '{Base(), Base()}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std::vector<Derived>'
   13 |     std::vector<Derived> vec = {Base{}, Base{}};
      |                                               ^
      |                                               |
      |                                               <brace-enclosed initializer list>
```

Разве `using Base::Base;` не добавило `Derived(const Base&) noexcept { }` в `Derived`? Если нет, то что произошло?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, `using Base<T>::Base;` не добавило `Derived(const Base&) noexcept { }` в `Derived`. Вместо этого для `Derived` при необходимости (неявно) создаются свои конструкторы копирования/ перемещения.

https://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue2356

Answer (score 1):

При наследовании, объявление using вводит имя из базового класса в область видимости производного класса, а не создает свои экземпляры переменных или функций.
Это - создать синоним для данных или функции, а не создать функцию с таким же именем в классе-наследнике.
Т.е. вы получаете доступ к членам класса `Base` через имя объекта класса `Derived`. Но копии не создаются. Вот в коде сравните размер

```
struct Base 
{
    int a;
    void foo(int){}
};

struct Derived : Base 
{
    using Base::Base;
};

int main() 
{ 
    Base b{};
    Derived d{};
    d.a = 1;
    cout << " Размер Base = " << sizeof(b) << ", размер Derived = " << sizeof(d) << endl;
}
```

В данном примере `Derived::foo()` - это синоним `Base::foo()`, а не копия функции с таким же именем в `Derived`. Также `Derived::a` - это синоним `Base::a`. Чаще всего, т.к. члены класса-родителя и так доступны к использованию в классе-наследнике, то особого смысла в использовании `using` нет.
Но это используется при выборе функции для запуска. Например:

```
struct A 
{
   void f(char) { cout << "In A::f()\n"; }
};

struct B : A 
{
   using A::f;    // A::f(char) теперь видится как B::f(char)

   void f(int) 
   {
      cout << "In B::f()\n";
      // Если есть using, то вызовется A::f(char)
      // Если нет using, то рекурсивно вызовется B::f(int) - `c` автоматически приведется к int
      f('c');
   }
};

int main() 
{
   B b;
   b.f('a');
}
```